# How do i make allowance for muliple lines when doing a string.scan

Tags: ruby

Here is an excerpt from the html I want to scan through.

```
<div class="text">
 <h3>
  <a href="http://www.faith.co.uk/">
   Rodeo Sinclair
  </a>
 </h3>
```

And here is my ruby code.

```
@doc = open(url) { |f| 
  @doc = f.read
}

output = @doc.scan(/<h3><a href=(.*?)>/)
```

This does not work because of the new lines and spaces in the html file. Is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could easily create a regular expression that would parse your HTML fragment.

However, I would like to encourage you to get in the habit of using an XML/HTML parser to interact with HTML.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

output = doc.css('div h3 a').each do |link|
    puts link.attr("href")
end
```

See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for a compelling argument against using regular expressions to parse HTML.

==EDIT== changed to an each loop

Comment: Thanks, would this grab all instances of that pattern in the HTML?

Comment: @bolshevik I changed it to an each loop to show how you'd get the href of each matching link

Answer (score 1):

Add (optional) spaces to the match:

```
@doc.scan(/<h3>\s*<a href=(.*?)>/)
```